# How to setup mysql replication in online server?

Tags: mysql

I want to set two mysql databases which one in online server and another in local server keep update each other.I found that it is possible to do using mysql replication. but how can i do it in online server. there are no option to edit my.ini files. How can I accomplish my requirement?

Comment: yes.what are the best cloud services that supports replication,database mirroring etc.?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO
->     MASTER_HOST='master_host_name',
->     MASTER_USER='replication_user_name',
->     MASTER_PASSWORD='replication_password',
->     MASTER_LOG_FILE='recorded_log_file_name',
->     MASTER_LOG_POS=recorded_log_position;``
```

Comment: Thank you.I'm new to mysql.can you please tell is this for slave?and how can I determine specific database to replicate